# k means clustering with fixed constraints (sum of specific attribute should be less than or equal 90,000)

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, mean, arcgis

Suppose I have 20,000 features on map, and each feature have many attributes (as well as the latitude and longitude). One of the attributes called population.

I want to split these 20,000 features into 3 clusters where the total sum of population of each cluster are equal to specific value 90,000 and features in each cluster should be near each others(ie will take locations in our consideration)

So, the output clusters should have the following conditions:

- Sum(population) of all points/items/features in cluster 1=90,000
- Sum(population) of all points/items/features in cluster 2=90,000
- Sum(population) of all points/items/features in cluster 3=90,000

I tried to use the k-mean clustering algorithm which gave me 3 clusters, but how to force the above constraint (sum of population should equal 90,000)

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: but also I have spatial/location constraints ie features in each cluster are near each other (neighbors)

Comment: So you should update your question and point out exactly what the criteria are .

Answer (score 1):

A turnkey solution will not work for you.

You'll have to formulate this as a standard constraint optimization problem and run a silver to optimize this. It's fairly straightforward: take the k-means objective and add your constraints...

Comment: What do you think if I took the k-means algorithm and updated it in order to take the above constrains in consideration ?

Comment: @Userx-101 Do you have a sound math-theory for this modification? If not, don't be optimistic. Minimum-sum-of-squares clustering (your objective) is NP-hard. Your constraints are somewhat like subset sum, which is NP-hard. This is a tough problem which can only be tackled by using as many assumptions/structure as possible (for your data). Your *undescribed* modification might directly lose any convergence proof or lead to other problems. An approach as described (e.g. mixed-integer convex-optimization) brings a lot of structure-exploitation for free. But your data is huge (for these solvers).

Comment: @Userx-101 you can try following the k-means *modification* tutorial at https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/same-size_k_means and modify it to satisfy your constraints. But I am fairly certain that approaching it from a *standard* constraint problem will find better solutions faster (and you are more likely able to use a library to do the heavy lifting). I agree with Sascha that is likely is NP-hard, so you'll only get a local optimum easily. But it may well be that a k-mrans modification based on that tutorial is good enough for you.